# How can I authenticate through application credentials to OpenStack using the CLI?

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, openstack, openstack-keystone

I know how to authenticate through user credentials and token to OpenStack via the `openstack` CLI. Now I would like to know how to use application credentials to authenticate.

Using `application_credential` or `application_credentials` as `auth_type`/`OS_AUTH_TYPE` only triggers a message about a plugin named like this not being found.

Sadly I could not find any documentation or even mention about this. Is there maybe a separate authentication plugin for the Keystone client needed?

The CLI version is 5.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
export OS_AUTH_TYPE=v3applicationcredential
export OS_AUTH_URL=<KEYSTONE-URI>
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_REGION_NAME=<REGION_NAME>
export OS_INTERFACE=public
export OS_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL_ID=<APPLICATION-CREDENTIAL-ID>
export OS_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL_SECRET=<APPLICATION-CREDENTIAL-SECRET>
```